# Utilizar funcion Replace en javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito utilizar replace en javascript para reemplazar todas las comillas dobles de un string por contrabarra y comillas dobles.

```
string = 'Esto es un "Test"';
resultado = string.replace(/"/gi, "\"");
```

Luego de utilizar el replace **Esto es un \"Test\"**
. Pero sin embargo, no modifica el string. Alguna idea?. Gracias desde ya!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes setear el replace a la variable que estas haciendo el replace

Una vez que busca las comillas dobles en el string y para poder reemplazarlas por '\"' deberas escapar la comilla para que no se rompa el script

```js
string = 'Esto es un "Test"';
string = string.replace(/"/g, "\\\"");  //escapamos la comilla
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para esto deberías **escapar la comilla y la barra invertida** de la forma en que comenta **Luisa** o también de esta forma:

```js
var string = 'Esto es un "Test"';
var resultado = string.replace(/"/gi, '\\"');
console.log(resultado);
```